# how can i connect the usb cable from my lg p350g into my computer to transfer its stuff?

Tags: usb-connection-mode

i have done it before but the notification does not appear its charges my phone but cannot connect the phones internal SD to my computer. Please help

Comment: If you go to *Settings* and follow the *More* item in the *Network* section, do you find an entry like *USB connection mode*? Or, when you connect your device, do those settings not pop-up asking you to connect?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect your phone to your computer, You get a pop-up showing a green android with one hand being a USB.
There, click on *Mount SD card* or an option similar to that.
You should be able to use the SD card as a flash drive.